# python beginner: reading a file and adding its integers

Tags: file, integer, addition

so i'm trying to pull numbers from a file numbers.txt and add them together. The program can currently pull the numbers one at a time and print them spaced out on one line. I now need it to total all of the values. The numbers in the file are: 9 19 15 17 5 and 17. The total should be 82 but it will only add the two number 17's and output 34.

def main():

```
numfile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
total = 0
for line in numfile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')

    print (line, end=' ')
    total = int(line)
    total += total

print ("\nEnd of file")   
print (total)

numfile.close()
```

main()

Answer (score 0):

> When You execute code `total = int(line)` - Main Error - resets the value of total

```
In [11]: numfile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

In [12]: total = 0

In [13]: for line in numfile:
   ....:     line = line.strip()
   ....:     print line,
   ....:     total += int(line)
   ....:
9 19 15 17 5 17

In [14]: total
Out[14]: 82
```